# View not updating when pushing new items in an Array - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a problem that, unfortunately, I was not able to solve in a while, even looking at related StackOverflow Q/A.

> I'm building an application using **MEAN** and I'm having an issue
>   when I need to render new items trough `ng-repeat`.
>
> I have lots of items stored in a MongoDB instance, and I'm perfectly
>   able to fetch all of them trough API calls.
>
> I need to show only 24 items at the very beginning, and 24 more every
>   time the user clicks on a **show more** button. I always need to
>   concatenate them after the old ones.
>
> It works perfectly with the first 24 items but It does not render
>   other items.
>
> When I try to log the new fetched items, I get them with no problems.
>   I'm able to see their attributes and so on.

This is a short cut of my items **View**:

```
<div class="myItem" ng-repeat="item in searchCtrl.items track by $index">
  . . . .
</div>
```

This is my **Show More Button**:

```
<a class="showMoreButton" ng-click="searchCtrl.goToNextPage()">show more</a>
```

This is a simplified version of my **Controller** also known as **searchCtrl**:

```
function SearchController($scope, ItemFactory) {

  var vm = this;

  //Needed for pagination, 24 items at a time, starting from page 1
  vm.searchParams = {
    size   : 24,
    page   : 1
  }      

  //Initialize Empty Array to Contain Items
  vm.items = [];

  /*Calling fetchItems to fetch the items the very 
    first time the Controller is called*/
  fetchItems();

  //Calls goToPage passing it a new page (It handles pagination)
  vm.goToNextPage = function() {
    var next = parseInt(vm.info.currentPage) + 1;
    vm.goToPage(next);
  };

  //Calls fetchItems after setting the new page
  vm.goToPage = function(page) {
    vm.searchParams.page = page;
    fetchItems();
  };      

  //Calls getItems and pushes the single items into vm.items
  function fetchItems(){
    ItemFactory.getItems(vm.searchParams).then(function(response){

        //iterates trough items
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.data.length; i++) {
          //Log current item
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.data[i]));
          //push current item into vm.items
          vm.items.push(response.data.data[i]);
        }

        //Print correctly the new items pool
        console.log(vm.items);

    }, function(error){
        $log.error(error);
    });
  }      

};
```

This is a simplified version of my **ItemFactory**:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('ItemFactory', 
                function ($http, API_URL) {

  //Getting items from API
  function getItems(params) {

    return $http.get(API_URL + '/item',{params: params}
    ).then(function success(response) {

        return response;
    });
  }

  return {
    getItems : getItems
  }

});
```

**Controller** binding to my view, it work as it should. I'm using this modularized approach and it always works perfectly:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
.config(itemRoute);

function itemRoute($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('index.items', {
            url             : 'index/items',
            parent          : 'index',
            templateUrl     : 'app/main-pages/items/items.html',
            controller      : 'SearchController',
            controllerAs    : 'searchCtrl'
    });
}
```

I also tried using `concat` instead of looping trough items with a `for` but the result does not change:

```
//Instead of looping
vm.items = vm.items.concat(response.data.data);
```

**Essentially**:

- I'm only able to render the first 24 items
- I can not render all the other items even if they get properly inserted into items array
- Items starting from 25 and so on do not get into the DOM
- I already tried using `$scope.$apply();` but I get `digest errors`

**Questions**:

1. What is causing this?
2. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance, if you need any clarification just post a comment below.

Comment: So I understand correctly - when you click your button and fire `goToNextPage()` which fires `fetchItems()` you are getting data back from that ajax call? Like, you can log that from the controller but nothing is getting rendered?

Comment: Exactly @RocketsRockets , only the first 24 items get into the DOM and shown.

Comment: can u post how your controller is being defined in html? i.e. `ng-controller=...`

Comment: Okay @RocketsRockets. I'm using a pretty modularized approach. All my Controllers work perfectly in this way. Edit incoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue broadcasting a message from `ItemFactory` when fetching new items and attaching a listener to that message in `SearchController`. When `ItemDataRefresh` gets broadcasted, then, `SearchController` concatenates the new data.

**ItemFactory**:

```
function getItems(params) {

    return $http.get(API_URL + '/item',{params: params}
    ).then(function success(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('refreshData', response.data);
        return response;
    });
}
```

**SearchController**:

```
function fetchItems(){
    ItemFactory.getItems(vm.searchParams).then(function(response){

      //When vm.items is empty
      if (!vm.items.length) {
        vm.items = vm.items.concat(response.data.data);
      }

      //on refreshData
      $scope.$on('refreshData', function(event, data){
        vm.items = vm.items.concat(data.data);
      });

    }, function(error){
        $log.error(error);
    });
}
```

I know that I should not use `rootScope` so I'm still looking for a way to make it work in a cleaner way.

I hope it will help someone.